# Failed to feed selector to a ClientFunction

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Please take a look at the structure below.
 
Is there any way to get 'Example 1' working? The idea is to avoid storing a 'css selector string' in a 'test' class.

***MyAccount.js***

```
    import { Selector} from "testcafe";

    export class MyAccount {
      constructor() { 
        this.box = {
          item_1: Selector("#item01");
          item_2: Selector("#item02");
        }
      }
    }
```

***clientFunctions.js***

```
    import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

    export const scrollInto = ClientFunction((selector) => {
        var element = window.document.querySelector(selector);    
        element.scrollIntoView();
    });
```

**EXAMPLE 1. (FAILED)**

```
    import { MyAccount } from "../MyAccount";
    import { scrollInto } from "../clientFunctions";

    const myAccount = new MyAccount();

    fixture("Feature A").page(process.env.url);

    test("Test 01", async t => {

      await scrollInto(myAccount.box.item_1);

    });
```

**EXAMPLE 2. (PASSED)**

```
    import { MyAccount } from "../MyAccount";
    import { scrollInto } from "../clientFunctions";

    const myAccount = new MyAccount();

    fixture("Feature A").page(process.env.url);

    test("Test 01", async t => {

      await scrollInto("#item01");

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the browser's [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method doesn't work with the TestCafe [`Selector`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/creating-selectors.html) API. Please change the `MyAccount` class in the following way to make your example work:

```js
export class MyAccount {
    constructor() { 
        this.box = {
            item_1: "#item01",
            item_2: "#item02"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I can use such approach as a solution, but in this case I will not be able to refer to page elements within a test like this //await t.click(myAcoount.box.item_1)//, instead of this I will have to use //await t.click(Selector(myAccount.box.item_1))//. But, in any case, it looks like there is not any better option. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a Selector into a ClientFunction through the [dependencies](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/clientfunction/constructor.html#optionsdependencies) option and override it later by calling [with](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/clientfunction/with.html) method.